# Passing the right variable to a modal from a list of clickable items in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am using React for a website for an open garden scheme that I organise. I have a component in which you can look at a specific garden (`garden.js`) and its associated images. I present these images as smaller versions of the original.

I am making a modal (`ImageModal.js`) that starts when you click an image and shows normal size of that image. I got the modal running, but I don't understand how to get the right image data into that modal.

This is my (gutted) code so far:

```
----------------------
Garden.js
----------------------
export default function Garden() {

  const [openImageModal, setOpenImageModal] = useState(false);
  
  //Removed: fetch the garden and image objects from the database, imports, css styling, etc

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{garden.title}</h1>
        <div>
        {
          images.map((image) => (
            <img
              src={image.image}   //base64 encoded blob
              key={image.id}      //id of the image in the db
              alt={garden.title}
              onClick={() => { setOpenImageModal(true); }}
            ></img>
          ))
        }
      </div>
      {openImageModal && <ImageModal closeImageModal={setOpenImageModal} />}
    </div>
  );
}

----------------------
ImageModal.js
----------------------
export default function ImageModal({ closeImageModal }) {
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => closeImageModal(false)}>x</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src={theProperImage}></img>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So my question is this: how do I get `{image.image}` from one of the images created by `images.map` into the modal so I can use it as (or in place of) `{theProperImage}`?

Hope I didn't forget anything to mention and thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a second state variable to store the clicked image or its id. Now just pass it as a prop to the modal.

Comment: @ChrisG Could you give me a small example? I am cobbling this together from various tutorials on YouTube and I am not that confident with React yet. I am sure I can make another state variable, but using it is a different matter. Pretty please?

Comment: Right, given a second state variable `imageId` you would use `onClick={() => { setOpenImageModal(true); setImageId(image.id); }}` as the click handler and `<ImageModal closeImageModal={setOpenImageModal} imageId={imageId} />` to pass it as prop. Next you need `function ImageModal({ closeImageModal, imageId })` and now you can use the value inside the modal component. (note that you've picked the worst way to learn React, which is why you immediately ended up here as soon as you hit the tiniest roadblock. you should learn JS basics first, then do the official React tutorials instead)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks! I do know my way around Javascript, just not comfortable with React yet. I will follow your advice and start from 0, but right now this was the last bit I needed to get my site working.